# How to Storing a loop as a string in a variable?

Tags: php, xml

My Code is like this :

```
<?php
        $HCode = 'IDJKT01';
        $CheckIn = '2016-02-01';
        $CheckOut = '2016-02-02';
        $Sgl = 1;
        $Dbl = 0;
        $Trp = 0;
        $RmGrade = 'DELUXE';

        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

                            <Request>

                                <BookingRequest>                   

                                    <HCode>".$HCode."</HCode>

                                    <RmGrade>".$RmGrade."</RmGrade>

                                    <CheckIn>".$CheckIn."</CheckIn>

                                    <CheckOut>".$CheckOut."</CheckOut> 

                                    <Sgl>".$Sgl."</Sgl> 

                                    <Dbl>".$Dbl."</Dbl> 

                                    <Trp>".$Trp."</Trp> 

                                    <Passenger Room='SGL'>

                                        <PassSex>M</PassSex>

                                        <PassLocalNm>Becks</PassLocalNm>

                                        <PassFirstNm> David </PassFirstNm>

                                        <PassLastNm> Beckham</PassLastNm>

                                    </Passenger>

                                </BookingRequest>

                            </Request>";
?>
```

I want to add loop in string.

For example as above, 
If $sgl = 1, then the number of passenger tag is 1

Other examples such as $sgl = 3, then the number of passenger tag is 3

Other examples such as $double = 1, then the number of passenger tag is 2

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: ok and? have you attempted anything?

Comment: You need to learn how to build strings, then: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
        $HCode = 'IDJKT01';
        $CheckIn = '2016-02-01';
        $CheckOut = '2016-02-02';
        $Sgl = 0;
        $Dbl = 1;
        $Trp = 0;
        $RmGrade = 'DELUXE';

        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>\n".
                "\t<Request>\n".
                "\t\t<BookingRequest>\n".
                "\t\t\t<HCode>".$HCode."</HCode>\n".
                "\t\t\t<RmGrade>".$RmGrade."</RmGrade>\n".
                "\t\t\t<CheckIn>".$CheckIn."</CheckIn>\n".
                "\t\t\t<CheckOut>".$CheckOut."</CheckOut> \n".
                "\t\t\t<Sgl>".$Sgl."</Sgl>\n". 
                "\t\t\t<Dbl>".$Dbl."</Dbl> \n".
                "\t\t\t<Trp>".$Trp."</Trp>\n";
for($i=0; $i< ($Sgl ? 1 : ($Dbl ? 2 : ($Trp ? 3 : 0))); $i++) {
        $xml .= "\t\t\t<Passenger Room=".($Sgl ? "'SGL'" : ($Dbl ? "'DBL'" : ($Trp ? "'TRP'" : "'SGL'"))).">\n".
                "\t\t\t\t<PassSex>M</PassSex>\n".
                "\t\t\t\t<PassLocalNm>Becks</PassLocalNm>\n".
                "\t\t\t\t<PassFirstNm>David</PassFirstNm>\n".
                "\t\t\t\t<PassLastNm>Beckham</PassLastNm>\n".
                "\t\t\t</Passenger>\n";
}
$xml .= "\t\t</BookingRequest>\n".
        "</Request>";
```

Result:

```
<Request>
        <BookingRequest>
            <HCode>IDJKT01</HCode>
            <RMGrade>DELUXE</RMGrade>
            <CheckIn>2016-02-01</CheckIn>
            <CheckOut>2016-02-02</CheckOut> 
            <Sgl>0</Sgl>
            <Dbl>1</Dbl> 
            <Trp>0</Trp>
            <Passenger Room="DBL">
                <PassSex>M</PassSex>
                <PassLocalNm>Becks</PassLocalNm>
                <PassFirstNm>David</PassFirstNm>
                <PassLastNm>Beckham</PassLastNm>
            </Passenger>
            <Passenger Room="DBL">
                <PassSex>M</PassSex>
                <PassLocalNm>Becks</PassLocalNm>
                <PassFirstNm>David</PassFirstNm>
                <PassLastNm>Beckham</PassLastNm>
            </Passenger>
        </BookingRequest>
</Request>
```

Personally, I'd reformat the XML like this:

```
<Request>
        <BookingRequest>
            <HCode>IDJKT01</HCode>
            <RMGrade>DELUXE</RMGrade>
            <CheckIn>2016-02-01</CheckIn>
            <CheckOut>2016-02-02</CheckOut> 
            <Sgl>0</Sgl>
            <Dbl>1</Dbl> 
            <Trp>0</Trp>
            <Passengers>
                <Passenger Room="DBL">
                    <PassSex>M</PassSex>
                    <PassLocalNm>Becks</PassLocalNm>
                    <PassFirstNm>David</PassFirstNm>
                    <PassLastNm>Beckham</PassLastNm>
                </Passenger>
                <Passenger Room="DBL">
                    <PassSex>M</PassSex>
                    <PassLocalNm>Becks</PassLocalNm>
                    <PassFirstNm>David</PassFirstNm>
                    <PassLastNm>Beckham</PassLastNm>
                </Passenger>
            </Passengers>
        </BookingRequest>
</Request>
```